# Error in ipw: How to deal with Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

I was trying to run inverse probability weighting by the following script:

```
temp1<-ipwpoint(exposure=bmi_ly,

 family="gaussian", numerator=~1, 
denominator=~ age+sex+pack_years+edu_cat+drinkstatus,data=devdata)

where 
bmi_ly=continuous (range 13-78), 
age=continuous (range 18-79), 
sex=dichotomous (1,2), 
pack_years= categorical (1,2,3) and 
drinkstatus=categorical (1,2,3).   

but it returns with an error msg
Er

ror in dnorm(tempdat$exposure, predict(mod1), sd(mod1$residuals))
```

Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

I tried to figure out the problem but couldn't. Can you guys help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Non-numeric categorical variables to one hot encoding or label encoding which will solve your issue.